# Why Is It Impossible To Save A File Opened With Internet Explorer Via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download a file from a website that I log into, however the save prompt is causing me issues.

I tried using sendkeys and that didn't actually send the key strokes, also tried downloading with xmlhttp after logging in with Internet Explorer. I don't understand why it is so difficult.

```
 'Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
  Sub login()

Const Url$ = "https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/user/login"
Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object, oButton As Object, HTMLdoc As Object
Dim UserName As String, Password As String
UserName = "yyyyy@zzzz.com"
Password = "password"

Dim ie As Object, myURL As String
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.navigate Url
    ie.Visible = True

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
    Set oLogin = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("form-control form-text required")(0)
    Set oPassword = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("form-control form-text required")(1)
    Set oButton = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary form-submit icon-before")(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    oLogin.Value = UserName
    On Error Resume Next
    oPassword.Value = Password
    On Error Resume Next
    oButton.Click

     myURL = "https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/download/index-ror-perf-download/2899"
     ie.navigate myURL
     'AppActivate "zzz@yyyy.net | Hedge Fund Research® - Internet Explorer"
     'Sleep 1
     Application.SendKeys ("%s")

 End Sub
```

Is there any simple ways to accomplish this? Everything opens up and logs in fine but I need to get past that save dialog, Thanks

EDIT:
     Request Headers

```
GET /download/index-ror-perf-download/2899 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.hedgefundresearch.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Referer: https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/indices/hfri-fund-weighted-composite-index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1864475516.1551721637; COOKIE_TOU=2019-03-04+11%3A47%3A19; cookiesession1=297E7ACEBCDZVZC3YAZR1VC8IWL6AF6D; has_js=1; _gid=GA1.2.2018233246.1554731723; SSESScd329e696f514d42291a588234027dae=G6jjp0oCZUb2FjW43IXgTVZAOsb2UbyoU7iawYa2erw

General:
Request URL: https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/download/index-ror-perf-download/2899
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 167.88.151.170:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: "_also tried downloading with xmlhttp after logging in with Internet Explorer_": the `XmlHttpRequest` is probably the good way to go, but authentication is done via the header of the request, not robotically on Internet Explorer. If you can share at least the HTML of the webbpage, someone can try to guess. Else, open Google Chrome, Ctrl + Shift + J to see the developer tools, go to Network tab, download your document manually and check for the corresponding XHR request (you can click on it and check the "Headers", that will tell you how to build it correctly).

Comment: You can try UIAutomation or switching to selenium basic. Also, see if there a download url generated when you manually perform the task that might be usable for urlmon or binary download. Also, look into xhr with authentication.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I will add the Request Header that I obtained following your instructions, How would I log in with this? Is there any tutorials you recommend, I am not too familiar with this.

Comment: @QHarr I will look into Selenium Basic looks very useful